# jquery selector to select a hidden input whose parent is same to the current elment

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the "hidden input" from the "a" tag. The hidden input is belonging to a "p" tag with an id of "controlBar". here is a screenshot to explain this a bit more.

[image]

Below is the selector I have come up with, but it's doesn't seem to pick out the target

```
alert($(this).parent("div").children('input[id*="QuestID"]:hidden:first').val());
```

in the context of the above snipplet (this) refers to the "a" tag circled in green

help me on this guys...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert($(this).parent().children('div').children('input:hidden:first').val());
```

In reply to you comment below:

```
alert($(this).parent().children('#controlBar').children('input:hidden:first').val());
```

Comment: This works @Saratis . But how do I further filter the "p" tag by its  id "controlBar" ?

Comment: Just change div to #controlBar

Comment: I think OP is missing something here. If he is targeting `#controlbar` then everything before it is completely useless. ID's are unique and he is wasting a lot of effort traversing parents and children when he doesn't need to.

Comment: @mrtsherman , the filters are needed as it is a repeated area. However, the id I put as "controlBar" for simplicity, and in actual use it is a class name.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - Ahh, I see. Glad you got a solution then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent("div").find('input[id*="QuestID"][type="hidden"]:first').val();
```

Comment: this is good , except it searches for all elements inside the parent div , when it should actually be searching only inside the "p" tag. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try change `children()` to `find()`. children only travels a single level down the DOM tree. your `parent("div")` is `<div class="group">`, so it needs to go deeper than `<p>` element.